# How to disable the brightness slider in the Gnome 3 aggregate menu?

Tags: 18.04, brightness, gnome-shell, ups

I have a desktop with a UPS connected to it. In the Gnome menu where I can log off I have another slider below the volume slider which appears to be the brightness slider and it doesn't work nor did I expect it to work. How can I remove this or how can I tell Gnome that, yes my computer has a battery but that doesn't mean it's a laptop or that brightness controls work with these monitors.

I checked all extensions offered for brightness on the Gnome website, looked at Gnome help and checked all I can find in dconf editor under /org/gnome, no luck.

Edit: I found this repository: https://github.com/dffischer/gnome-aggregatemenu-hider I installed waf but but the hider fails to build:

```
$ ./waf --targets=Brightness configure build
Setting top to                           : gnome-aggregatemenu-hider 
Setting out to                           : gnome-aggregatemenu-hider/build 
'configure' finished successfully (0.004s)
Waf: Entering directory `gnome-aggregatemenu-hider/build'
Waf: Leaving directory `gnome-aggregatemenu-hider/build'
Build failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gnome-aggregatemenu-hider/.waf-2.0.11-d998e576e79d26a553b299ec4e56967b/waflib/Runner.py", line 245, in task_status
    return tsk.runnable_status()
  File "gnome-aggregatemenu-hider/.waf-2.0.11-d998e576e79d26a553b299ec4e56967b/waflib/Task.py", line 364, in runnable_status
    new_sig=self.signature()
  File "gnome-aggregatemenu-hider/.waf-2.0.11-d998e576e79d26a553b299ec4e56967b/waflib/Task.py", line 346, in signature
    self.sig_vars()
  File "./template.py", line 15, in sig_vars
    super().sig_vars()
TypeError: super() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)
```

Comment: This would probably requiring writing an extension. I did not find extensions that would disable the control, however.

Answer (score 4):

If you can live without the power indicator you may try the following workaround.

Install a [GNOME shell extension](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75530/how-do-i-install-and-manage-gnome-shell-extensions) called [Extend Panel Menu](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1201/extend-panel-menu/). This would "*move the Power/Network/Volume/User/Date/Notifications menus to the status area*" from the aggregate menu. The brightness control slider should be in the power indicator.

Then from the extension's preferences disable the power indicator (and other unnecessary indicators).

Comment: That's a creative workaround, but I like to keep the menu as it is and just remove this one slider. :)

Answer (score 3):

I fixed it by passing the `acpi_backlight=none` parameter to the kernel. Apparently this is related to the way external monitors are handled.

The issue still happens on GNOME 3.36 and kernel 5.11.

Comment: Thanks I will try it out.